# Bundles.RenderScripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cassette

I have 3 files
•   jquery.ui.core
•   jquery.ui.widget
•   jquery.ui.tabs

I have to get it referrer in this order itself

But Bundles.RenderScripts add reference in the alphabetical order think.

I tried explicitly done Bundles.Reference the 3 files in the order. It didn’t work.

How can I specify the order I need?

Answer (score 1):

Adding scripts by wildcard defaults to loading them in alphabetical order, which is typically not what you want. CSS and JavaScript files frequently need to be added in a specific (non-alphabetic) order. You can mitigate this risk by adding a custom IBundleOrderer implementation, but explicitly adding each file is less error prone. For example, you might add new assets to a folder in the future which might require you to modify your IBundleOrderer implementation.

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.ibundleorderer%28VS.110%29.aspx

Source: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Your anwser is help full to me

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by adding those script file name in Bundle.txt file.
see
http://getcassette.net/documentation/v1/configuration/bundle-descriptor-file